# Intermittent CORS errors on Google Drive /files/'fileid'

Tags: google-drive-api

The same day I got v80 of Chrome my localhost web app that accesses both the spreadsheet and drive api's started to fail.  I use /file on drive to find the files to load.  This works fine. I then go to load each file with /file/myfileid?access_token=mytoken.  Most of the time it comes back with CORS errors

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1PFCs5EHJVQBziah2bif9qVBzsCMYLcJ_?access_token=mytoken&corpora=user&alt=media' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Each time I am trying to load 3 different files.  Every couple tries one of them works without the error.

As I said, this was working fine until this week.  I have a test version I built last week serving from a local XAMPP and it also is failing.  My dev environment is Angular 9 in VSCode.

I am at a loss trying to figure out what is happening?

Comment: Can you please share the code which is failing? Please make sure to sanitise it first, of course.

Answer (score 0):

While I was putting a small example of this to post here I discovered the issue. I am using the angularx-social-login add-in for logging a user into the app.  The code mismanaged the OAUTH token received back from Google.  I had been using the token in a new Param() and had been working fine.  I have moved it to a HEADER with a BEARER token and everything works fine.  Still not sure why it worked every once in a while.